# iOS SDK (xcodebuild): Clang error cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, clang, xcodebuild

Randomly im getting the following error from `xcodebuild` (iOS 5.0 SDK - Apple LLVM 3.0):

```
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
Verify exit code of build task 'CompileC SomeViewController.m'
Build task failed without generating error messages.
```

On the next try it works fine, and than randomly the error happens again.
Im using `xcodebuild` on an continuous integration system, so every time this happens the build goes red :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing clean builds every time on your continuous integration system? Can you include more output from the log when this happens?

Comment: Yes clean on every build. There isn't more output that has to do with this error. :(

Comment: It would help to see the compile command that is being run by the build system, to figure out where the extra -o is coming from. That was the output I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode 4.3.1 update with the LLVM 3.1 compiler solved the problem for me.